# Alternative for v-calendar in vuetify3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have installed vue.js 3 and added vuetify 3. What I want is to use v-calendar component to my Home.vue however I am not able to find it in third version.

I checked many GitHub repositories but in all cases authors install vuetify 2.

**Question**

Do I really need to downgrade my vuetify to 2nd version to access the calendar or maybe there is another way to access this component? Maybe an alternative that contains similar features?

I want to create event planner so casual date picker is not an option. It must have a visible event titles with option to switch between weeks and months.

Comment: Check https://vcalendar.io/

Comment: @Tolbxela thanks for suggestion but it is just a date picker and I want to have visible event titles like i v-calendar

Comment: Please rephrase your question, you cannot ask recommendation for packages/librairies. Only focus on the downgrading part.